# Refresh dist directory when uploading new files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm actually developping an application using Angular2 and Node.js.

I started the Angular2 part with Angular-cli.

I have an issue concerning file upload. In the application, I can create Albums. In the Album form, there is a file input. In the backend, I store files, actually images, in a files directory in my assets.

The problem is, when I try to display this images, they don't display. I need to re-run "ng build" to see them. 
I assume this is due to the fact this newly uploaded files are not present in the dist directory.

- Is there a way to dynamically refresh dist directory after the file upload ?
- Is it a correct way to directly copy files in the dist (and still in assets) directory during the upload ?

Have a good day,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assets folder is source code.
The dist folder is compling results, that for application run time reference.
Actually you can upload to dist.

But I think you create other directory (like `http://{domian}/upload/`) for upload files will be better. get image with relative path from root.

You are upload files in local via `ng serve`, right?
Two ways for your refenereces:
1. try to deploy dist to server, then upload files, you will get the images.
2. using `lite-server`

```
$ npm i -g lite-server
$ ng build --watch
$ lite-server --baseDir="dist"
```

The upload files should be in dist/{upload}/{image}.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your answer  !  I understood that my images have to be in assets if i want them to be displayed, is it true  ? I already tried to upload files in a folder outside of assets but images did not show... Should i put this folder in assets folders array in angular-cli.json ?

Comment: I understood that my images have to be in assets if i want them to be displayed, is it true ? **Ans: No**. Should i put this folder in assets folders array in angular-cli.json ? **Ans: not the root cause, doesn't matter**. **Please read my updated answer as above.**