# Uploaded picture can not be displayed before an angular code new compilation or a server reboot

Tags: angular, caching, compilation, image-uploading, file-access

I have no clue left...

### Context

A 2 pages Angular application :

- one page to list pictures (pictures files are store in "assets/picture")
- one page to upload picture, by post them to a node/express API which is in charge to move picture into "assets/picture" angular folder

### Issue

Uploaded picture can not be displayed [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tTnT.png) using src="assets/image/fileName.jpg" (got a 404) **before an angular code new compilation or a server reboot**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tTnT.png)

Note : I can display a picture preview in upload page by using src="data:image/jpeg;base64..." method [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twb3c.png)

Intuition : Im afraid I'm not suppose to upload files in Angular assets folder but somewhere else may be at the root of the node server. Here is my current file organization : [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWjdo.png)

### Code

#### Node server

to move picture in angular "assets/image" folder
`pictureFile.mv('src/assets/picture/'+ fileName);`

#### Angular

`<img class="picture" src="'src/assets/picture/'{{fileName}}">`

Regards,
Valink

Answer (score 0):

your sources of FE application lie under /src folder. it is also a place where you are trying to save pictures. however the "runtime" application lies under /dist folder. You can save your pictures to runtime folder and it will work as you want as long as you dont rebuild your FE application

```
pictureFile.mv('dist/assets/picture/'+ fileName);
```

When you rebuild your appliction with this code it will just rewrite the assets folder. You also can make a trick and save one file to `/dist` and a copy to `/src` and it will work in all cases of local development. However it won't do if you try to deploy it somewhere (as your local /src will no longer be updated from the remote server). The correct way would be usage of some persistence like [gridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and these clarifications. 

I tried what you told me : "You can save your pictures to runtime folder" and indeed it's working fine when I serve my Angular application (dist folder) with Node.

However, my current "runtime" application does not lies under /dist folder ; I'm currently using Angular local/dev server (using `ng serve` and webpack) to benefit from livereload.

May be I should treat uploaded pictures as server files and not angular application files ; I tried to store them in a server root folder but Angular application can't access to them anymore.

Comment: Related to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788923/refresh-dist-directory-when-uploading-new-files but I need the livereload